# How to replace string with variable in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I have this code that I am struggling a little bit with:

```
$NumberOfProfiles = Read-Host "Enter a number of profiles"
$Directory = "C:\Users\Apple\Folder(1..HowMuchProfilesCreated\Text.txt"
Variable1 = "Plane"
Variable2 = "Yacht"
Variable100 = "Bike"
while ($NumberOfProfiles -gt 0) { 
(Get-Content $Directory) | %{$_.Replace("Car", "Don'tKnowWhatToPutHere")} | Set-Content $Directory 
$NumberOfProfiles--
```

The Text.txt file is same in all the folders and contains the same string I wish to change (e.g. "Car" in this case), but the new string should come from variables that I have declared before and(or may be it is better to use array?)

E.g. $NumberOfProfiles = 10 and I create 10 folders where are exactly the same Text.txt and I need the "Car" to be replaced with Variable1 in folder1, Variable2 in folder2 and so on.

Comment: not sure if this helps, but you can call paramters passed into the ps script with 
param(
[string]$<variablename>
)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can construct the name of variable, you can use `Get-Variable`. An example to illustrate:

```
$Variable1 = "Bike"
$FolderID = 1
Get-Variable -Name "Variable$FolderID" -ValueOnly
```

Will result in

```
Bike
```